# change .mp3 file format to .aac file format in android using java programming

Tags: java, android, mp3, aac

I have one .mp3 file and I have to **convert** it into **.aac file format**.I have made one android app and it will only use .aac files.I have seen many questions on stackoverflow based on this.But didn't get any right solution with code.
So please help with the **coding part without using ffmpeg library**.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for not using ffmpeg?

Comment: If ffmpeg is not available ,then what will be your approach @Mauker